# If condition inside dynamic option in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an AJAX response I am creating `option` elements. An example is given below :

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
  html += '<option value=' + i + '>' + (i == 0) ? '-' : i + '</option>';  
}
```

It's returning me an error, but when I use this it's working fine:

```
for (var i = 0; i <=4; i++) {
  html += '<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>';  
}
```

What am I doing wrong with the `if` condition? In place of `0` I want to show `-` in the dropdown. Please help me.

Comment: Put your `a ? b : c` in parentheses.

Comment: sorry for posting now i find the solution :   (i == 0 ? '-' : i)

Comment: Dont forger to wrap the value `i` in `""`

Answer (score 5):

The issue is because segments of the the ternary are being misinterpreted as part of the string concatenation. To fix this wrap the entire ternary expression in parentheses:

```
for (var i = 0; i < = 4; i++) {
  html += '<option value=' + i + ' >' + (i == 0 ? '-' : i) + '</option>';  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rory McCrossan 's will fix your problem. I want to add that if can target modern browser, this will work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < = 4; i++) {
  html += `<option value="${i}">${i == 0 ? '-' : i}</option>`;  
}
```

Note that you should avoid creating HTML like this. Use [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) instead.